# Netbeans 11.3 "Cannot perform Show Javadoc here"

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc, netbeans-11

Showing Javadoc for standard libraries (java.base, ...) is working fine in my setup.

But including Javadoc for additional libraries fails all the time. I am looking for a hint, what can be done to fix this problem or to get more output for the root cause of this problem.

I have the following source code:

```
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;

public class JavaTestAoolication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SerialPort.getCommPorts();
    }
}
```

I try to add javadoc path for this library via menu *Tools -> Java Platforms* and tab *javadoc*.

This results in the following entries in the netbeans configuration file `~/.netbeans/11.3/config/Services/Platforms/org-netbeans-api-java-Platform/default_platform.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE platform PUBLIC "-//NetBeans//DTD Java PlatformDefinition 1.0//EN" "http://www.netbeans.org/dtds/java-platformdefinition-1_0.dtd">
<platform default="yes" name="JDK 11 (Default)">
    <properties>
        <property name="platform.ant.name" value="default_platform"/>
    </properties>
    <javadoc>
...
        <resource>https://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/javadoc/</resource>
        <resource>file:/usr/share/htl-libjserialcomm-java/2.6.1/javadoc/api/</resource>
...
   </javadoc>
</platform>
```

Selecting context menu -> Show Javadoc on `SerialPort.getCommPorts()` always results in the message:
**Cannot Perform show Javadoc here**.

But the link is existing:
https://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/javadoc/com/fazecast/jSerialComm/SerialPort.html

And also the local folder is existing (without symbolic links):

```sh
$ ls -la /usr/share/htl-libjserialcomm-java/2.6.1/javadoc/api/com/fazecast/jSerialComm/SerialPort.html 
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 115981 Apr  9 17:02 /usr/share/htl-libjserialcomm-java/2.6.1/javadoc/api/com/fazecast/jSerialComm/SerialPort.html
```

I also try to use `file://` instead of `file:/`. No success.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: I experienced similar problems to you, but there is a fairly simple workaround:

- Download and unzip the source of the Fazecast code.
- In NetBeans Use **Tools > Library Manager** to reference the locally unzipped source.

Here are the details:

- Go to https://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/ and select the option to download the zip file, as shown in the top right of the screen.
- The downloaded file is named **Fazecast-jSerialComm-v2.6.1-0-gf3d1e89.zip**. Unzip that. The `*.java` source files for the project will be in the unzipped directory `...\Fazecast-jSerialComm-v2.6.1-0-gf3d1e89\Fazecast-jSerialComm-f3d1e89\src\main\java\com\fazecast\jSerialComm`.
- In NetBeans select **Tools > Library Manager** then click **New Library...** to create an entry for *Fazecast*. Then, for that new entry:

  - Click the *Classpath* tab and click the **Add JAR/Folder...** button, and navigate to your download of **jSerialComm-2.6.1.jar**.
  - Click the *Sources* tab and navigate to the parent directory of the `com.fazecast` package in the unzipped source directory. In my case this was `D:\Downloads\FazecastJSerialComm\Fazecast-jSerialComm-v2.6.1-0-gf3d1e89\Fazecast-jSerialComm-f3d1e89\src\main\java`
  - It's counterintuitive, but you don't need to enter anything on the *Javadoc* tab!

Once you have done that, close and reopen your source file that's calling Fazecast methods and the javadoc should work. Here's an example for `SerialPort.getCommPorts()`, where I inserted `HELLO WORLD!!!` in the javadoc of that method to demonstrate that the local source was being accessed:

[image: FazecastJavadoc]

Notes:

- My environment was Windows 10, NetBeans 11.3 and JDK 14, and I created a simple Ant project.
- You could [open an issue report](https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm/issues) with Fazecast on the issue of not being able to access the online javadocs from NetBeans, since I don't think that is a NetBeans issue. You could also ask them to consider providing a downloadable javadoc file for jSerialComm.
- An additional benefit of linking to the Fazecast source in NetBeans is that you can open their code by clicking the *Open source in editor* icon in the javadoc window, as shown in the screen shot above. **Navigate > Go to Source** or **CTRL + Shift + B** also work if the cursor is on a Fazecast method.

Comment: Using Tool -> Libraries to add global libraries with there Javadoc works fine. It is not only a work around for this issue, it's the much more better way than to add javadoc paths to the platform definition. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, _Tools > Libraries_ is the way to go for all third party software outside of the JDK. And if that software make its source available for download (as Fazecast did), you can follow the approach described above to generate its javadocs and access the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a maven project then there is a really nice feature. After adding the library to the pom.xml, go  the project tree, find your library, right-click -> Download Javadoc.

[image]

And that's it! No mo hassle.

[image]